# Failed to load resource Jump.js

Tags: javascript, github, npm, github-pages, npm-scripts

I'm still a rookie when it comes to NPM. I usually just build websites without it. I want to implement smooth scroll using Jump.js.

It works fine when I user the live server extension for VScode but once uploaded to Github and viewed It,

**I just get:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404!

**Heres the my link:**

```
import jump from './node_modules/jump.js/dist/jump.module.js';
```

Comment: Hi @NickEast, github pages will load you index.html and your statics files. Could you please show us your project repo?

Comment: @OscarLópez here is the link to my repo https://github.com/NickEast12/NickEast12.github.io,

Answer (score 0):

Did you initiate the site using "npm init"? And you shouldn't specify /node_modules/ because due to how NPM works, it looks in the /node_modules/ per default looking for the package that you are trying to include..

I don't understand how you are viewing it on Github, this might help as well. Are you hosting your site using Github?

Comment: I host my site on Github, and yes i used npm init to create my package.json file. I an absolute NPM rookie

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I've solved my own problem.

It was to do with the path to the folders, I moved my dependancies to the root of my folder, probably not best practice!